# Animate expansion of ListView when a View in it is turned visible

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I currently have a button in each row of my ListView. When I press it, there is a chance that another View (that is gone) becomes visible. This means it takes up space and the ListView item increases in size. Is there an easy way to animate the expansion in size for the ListView item?

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom list view and here's following link might helps you.you can download code from here
http://download.androidhive.info/